# android: eclipse graphic layout view can see layer-list

Tags: android, android-layout, xml-drawable

i'm trying to build a layout-list for layer drawable

this is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/sign"
    android:id="@+id/sign"/>
</layer-list>
```

this is the error in the graphic layout:

```
com.android.layoutlib.bridge.MockView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup
Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log
The following classes could not be found:
- item (Fix Build Path, Edit XML)
- layer-list (Fix Build Path, Edit XML)
```

someone please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I pasted this in a new file in my current project, saved and rebuilt without a glitch.
Have you cleaned your project and tried rebuilding?

Comment: As i said i wanted to see the layout on the eclopse xml graphic layout tab. for preview. this is where i had error. can u see it there?